# Ant-Build-Script does not remove less.js reference from index.html

Tags: less, html5boilerplate

I use the html5boilerplate ant-build-script

For css i use less, thats the way i bound it in:

```
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="less/style.css"> -->
<!-- Less: Nur für Dev Setup -->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/style.less">
<script src="less/less-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

The build script only changes the *.less -> *.css but leaves the less.js in the html.

For cfg i added these two lines to my build/config/project.properties

```
build.css.less = true
file.root.stylesheet = style.less
```

Is there a way, that this line gets removed from the index.html?

```
<script src="less/less-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found it in the Wiki:

https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/wiki/Compiling-LESS-CSS